# how to append element to array with specific index in php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, push

I am new to php. 
I am trying to get key and value of each element in special array. I want to save/push them into another array start from zero index.
Of course (foreach loop) is the best tool here. Please help me BY YOUR CODE.
I know describing this problem is a bit hard, so I have some drawings for you.

```
$info = array(
    <--key-->     <--value--> 
    [10] => 'apple',
    [8] => 'orange',
    [2] => 'banana',
    [23] => 'peach',
)

now I want to have an array like this:

$myGoal = array(
  <-key->   <--------value---------> 
    [0] => array('10'=>'apple'),
    [1] => array('8'=>'orange'),
    [2] => array('2'=>'banana'),
    [3] => array('23'=>'peach')
)
```

I guess the code I need should be something like below:

```
$info = array(
    [10] => 'apple',
    [8] => 'orange',
    [2] => 'banana',
    [23] => 'peach',
)

$index = 0;
$myGoal = array();
foreach($info as $amount => $friut){
     $myGoal[$index] = [$amount][$friut];
     $index++;
}
```

I'll be thank of anybody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the syntax `$myGoal[$index] = [$amount][$friut];`

The part after the equals sign is creating an array with a single value of `$amount` and then tries to index into the array with the value of `$friut` which does not exists.

You could update the syntax to add an array to the index with `key => value`

Change

```
$myGoal[$index] = [$amount][$friut];
```

to

```
$myGoal[$index] = [$amount => $friut];
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [10] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [8] => orange
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => banana
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [23] => peach
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/0EXNd)

As @[kaczmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460810/kaczmen) points out, if you only want to append you don't need the index and you could use

```
$myGoal[] = [$amount => $friut];
```

Comment: You can also drop `$index` variable and make it `$myGoal[] = ...` if you only care about appending.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you intialize an array after that store the key value into a new array.

```
$info = array("10" => 'apple',"8" => 'orange',"2" => 'banana',"23" => 'peach');
$new=array();
foreach($info as $key=>$info1)
{
    $new[] = [$key=>$info1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `array_chunk` using a chunk size of 1.

```
$myGoal = array_chunk($info, 1, true);
```

Be sure to set the third argument to `true` to preserve the keys.

---

Also, not directly related to what you're asking, but I'd like to suggest that using amount as an array key is risky. If you ever have the same amount of two items, the second one will overwrite the first.

Comment: your idea was the shortest way and the result is OK, tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`, You do not need to declare the `$index=0` if you want to start it by `0`. You can just use `$n[]` it will automatic start from `0` index

```
 array_walk($info,function($v,$k)use(&$n){$n[]=[$k=>$v];});
 print_r($n);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/DTACm